# Bot giving template answers

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

When interacting with Botfather, the Botfather will present template answers (canned responses?) to commands (e.g. enable/disable buttons). How can a client do that or is that possible with custom clients?

Example canned response the Botfather generates:
[image]

Comment: Could elaborate you question? [Editmessagereplymarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) should be enough?

Comment: Added example, can markup achieve that? Would appreciate an answer with code example if possible.

Comment: Seems like Inline Keyboards https://core.telegram.org/bots#inline-keyboards-and-on-the-fly-updating are the answer?

Comment: Yea, those are Inline Keyboards, they can be edited on-the-fly to create your own custom menu.

Comment: Just one reminder, don't forget to enable **Inline Mode** for your bot, tell the BotFather `/setinline` to do so!

Comment: Not necessary for inline keyboard replies it seems

Comment: Ahh. If you need the keyboard to appear below the input field (like the image), instead off inside the 'chat' area, It thought it would be required! ;)